# jQuery Tokeninput retrieve token on page browse

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

How do I save tokens used in the previous search while jumping from page to page in a website ?
When I visit the page again I'd like to get my old search criteria tokens back.

`caching: true` works well but I am not sure how to retrieve the old tokens

```
$('#searchinput').tokenInput(searchServiceUrl, {
    theme: "facebook",
    queryParam : "param",
    preventDuplicates: true,
    tokenDelimiter: "|",
    minChars: 1,
    hintText: "Type your search criteria here",
    noResultsText: "No Results found. Please refine your search...",
    searchingText: "Fetching results ...please wait...",
    allowCustomEntry: true,
    searchDelay: 2,
    resultsLimit: 10,
    allowFreeTagging: false,
    selectToEdit: true,
    crossDomain: false,
    caching: true,
    onAdd: function (item) {
        var selectedValues = $('#searchinput').tokenInput("get");
        $.each(selectedValues , function(i, val) { 
            var id = selectedValues[i].id.split(")");
        });
```

Comment: That's going to be tough to accomplish with just Javascript. Generally speaking, the type of stateful response you're talking about is accomplished using a cookie or some server-side storage, for which you're going to need functionality on the server-side. You may be able to carry values from page to page using just Javascript in some cases, but there are easy ways to make it break. And maintaining any values after the user navigates away from your domain is going to require a cookie or some other kind of storage.

Comment: No i am nto trying to do that. But could you please tell me how to retreive the saved tokens and display in text field when the page loads again.

Comment: Something else you might consider using is HTML 5 local storage. Would this method work for you?